# как правильно удалять данные из DataGridView с помощью Entity Framework

Tags: c#, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview, entity

имеется bindingSource и к нему привязаны bindingNavigator и простой DataGridView. показываю в нем данные при загрузке формы

```
bindingSource.DataSource = db.parom.ToList();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> 

1. если у bindingNavigator в методе Click на кнопке удаления ничего не писать,
   то визуально строка из грида удаляется, но после db.SaveChanges(); ничего не удаляется.
2. если у bindingNavigator в методе Click на кнопке удаления писать:

   db.parom.Remove((parom)bindingSource.Current);

то после db.SaveChanges(); удаляется следующая, а не выделенная строка. при этом визуально из грида удаляется правильная строка.

3. если у bindingNavigator в методе Click на кнопке удаления писать:

   ```
   db.parom.Remove((parom)bindingSource.Current);
   bindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
   ```

тогда удаляется 2 строки.

**вопрос как правильно удалять данные ?**

Comment: однако смотрю сильно сложный вопрос для знатоков ?

Comment: не претендую на "знатока", но пофиг (=__=) КМК, *правильно* удалять только из связанной коллекции источника данных, которая реализует интерфейс `INotifyCollectionChanged` и её элементы реализуют интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged`, а режим привязки данных указан двухсторонний `Binding  Mode=TwoWay`.